# Stability of planet-enclosing shell supported by atmosphere

Tags: gravity, planets, air, stability

I understand that a hollow spherical shell of uniform density gives net zero gravitational attraction to objects inside it. So in vacuum, a ball at the centre of a spherical shell would not be stable in its position. Any slight deviation would continue and the ball would collide with the inside of the shell.

Would this be different in the presence of an atmosphere? Specifically, if the inner planet is massive enough to have an atmosphere that extends beyond the shell, and the shell is not sealed so that the atmosphere flows through in places.

I am imagining that the air pressure on the surface of the shell would be greater on the inside than the outside due to the thickness of the shell. This would have no net effect when the planet is at the centre of the shell, but any deviation would lead to the part of the shell nearest the planet being in higher pressure atmosphere. Would this lead to the difference in pressure between inside and outside being greater at that point than others, pushing the shell and planet apart to restore the planet to the centre?

My thinking is that the net outwards force on the shell at the point furthest from the planet will be less than the net outwards force on the shell at the point closest to the planet, due to there being a greater pressure difference across the thickness of the shell. Am I missing any effects that would prevent or counteract this?

---

*This idea came to me as an extension of one of the suggestions in [this worldbuilding answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/1155/109).*

Comment: Dyson Sphere, anyone?

Answer (score 2):

There would be a slight restorative force from the gravitational pull of the atmosphere itself.

First, imagine an ocean world with a very small core. If the core was more dense than the ocean it will be "sink" to the center.

Similarly, if your "core" was a shell, it would also "sink" to the center.

Thus, if you had both a sphere and a shell they would both tend towards the center, aligning to each other through the gravity of the ocean. The same restorative forces would exist with a very light "ocean" of gas; they would just be much much weaker.

This restorative force may not be enough to overcome instability that may come from rotating.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the positive feedback effects of winds flowing from high to low pressure areas as the shell moves. At best you would have a parachute effect to slow things down.

Comment: I imagine two effects from wind due to the atmosphere being compressed as the shell moves towards the planet: 1. wind flowing from inside the shell to the outside. 2. wind flowing away from the pressurised volume in all directions around the inside of the shell. I would expect these two effects to oppose each other, and it is not clear to me which would have a greater effect. Only one of them causes positive feedback. Do you have evidence that it would be the positive feedback that dominates the negative feedback?

Comment: No proof - I imagine the maths is quite complex. OTOH this argument should apply to any fluid. You could try it in a swimming pool!

Comment: If I had a sufficiently massive ball to create a significant radial pressure difference and a sufficiently large swimming pool, then I wouldn't have asked here... :)

Comment: @DirkBruere I believe you are wrong, consider the situation where the inner planet is not centered inside the shell and not moving. Intuitively, this would result in the inner planet moving back to teh center, this proves that there must bee speeds (however small) at which the effect must be enough to prevent the inner planet from colliding with the shell.